# Error while exporting plots results from cor function in a for loop over subfolders

Tags: raster, r, for-loop, correlation

I'm trying to plot the results from `cor` function that is running over multiple subfolders that contain TIF files. The process I have followed so far didn't work. It seems there is a problem while running the `sampleRandom` function but I cannot figure out what is the problem. Below is the code and then the error message

```
# define root folder 
setwd("./Bajio")
# list of sulfoders 
subf<-list.dirs(full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
# define outpath 
outpath <- "./Bajio_mes"
#create output directory
dir.create(outpath)
# define the output names
outfiles <- paste0(outpath, subf)
# define the output format
extension(outfiles) <- 'jpeg'
#running the for loop
for(j in 1:length(subf)){
    print(subf[j])
    h <- list.files(path=subf[j], recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE,pattern='.tif')
    print(h)
    d <- brick(h)
    e <- cor(sampleRandom(d[],size= ncell(d) * 0.5 ), method = "pearson")
    f <- corrplot(e, method = "number",col= colorRampPalette(c("black","pink", "red"))(10))
    f<-jpeg(f,outfiles[j]
    }
```

After running the code I obtain the following:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sampleRandom’ for signature ‘"matrix"’
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sampleRandom` needs the whole brick (or raster) fed to it, you are feeding it the vector of values with `d[]`.

Reproducing your error, minimally:

```
> r1 =raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))
> r2 =raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))
> b = brick(r1,r2)
> sampleRandom(b[], 5)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sampleRandom’ for signature ‘"matrix"’
```

Sampling from the brick:

```
> sampleRandom(b, 5)
     layer.1 layer.2
[1,]      10      10
[2,]       8       8
[3,]       1       1
[4,]       7       7
[5,]       4       4
```

Comment: You're right it has to work with the whole brick. I've made the change but then I obtain the following error
`Error in switch(units, in = res, cm = res/2.54, mm = res/25.4, px = 1) * : non-numeric argument to binary operator`
It seems more related to exporting the jpeg but even if a change the margins and other variables it hadn't work. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: I've got you past your first error - could you mark this as answered and then ask about the next error? Do some diagnostics first - like working out which function call is breaking - and then post it up.